# How to Overlay One Image on Another Using the Nokia Imaging SDK

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I am pulling an image from the device's MediaLibrary and displaying it on the phone screen. In this process, I am resizing the image, while maintaining the aspect ratio, so that none of the image is cut off when displayed on the phone screen. I would then like to overlay this resized image onto a blank image of the exact dimensions of the phone screen. The result that is required is the resized image centered on this new 'backdrop' image, probably with a foreground of PhoneChromeBrush so the image stands out on this background. I do not want to blend these images together at all, just simply place the actual picture from the MEdiaLibrary on top of this 'backdrop' image. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why can't you blend them? Look at the blend options, there are many, one of them does what you want.

Comment: ok Thanks, do you know of any good samples or could demonstrate how to blend two images of different sizes into a single image?

Comment: Well depends what you want, the size doesn't matter when blending since they will be resized to fit together - but that's probably not what you want. Take a look at this answer though, it should help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531492/nokia-imaging-sdk-customize-blendfilter